# Proving whether A, B, and C are on the straight line.

Tags: vectors

*Question:*

If vectors **a, b, c** are position vectors of **A, B,** and **C**, with respect **O** respectively, and $3$**OA** $+ 2$**OB** $- 5$**OC** $= 0$, prove that **A, B,** and **C** are in the same straight line.

*Solution:*

If A, B and C are in the same straight line, **OA** $=$ **OB** $=$ **OC**. But that is to prove. How do I prove with only one equation given?

Comment: You introduce (lower case) $a$, $b$, $c$ in the beginning and then never mention them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By simple rearrangement, we have $$\textbf{c}=\dfrac{3}{5}\textbf{a}+\dfrac{2}{5}\textbf{b}$$Consider $AC=\textbf{c}-\textbf{a}=\frac{-2}{5}(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})$ which is parallel to $AB=(\textbf{b}-\textbf{a})$ but A is the common point, so they are colinear